# ubuntu 11.04 VGA mode not supported?

Tags: ubuntu

I have sucessfully installed ubuntu 11.04(32 bit).. when booting the system my monitor says   **VGA Mode not supported**?
How can i recover this?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too.

To fix it, first use the installation disk to boot into recovery mode ("Recover a broken system"). You have to select a few options and it looks like the beginning of the installer but it isn't. It will give you an option to run a shell with your system partition selected. Once you're in a shell, edit the file /etc/default/grub and uncomment the line "GRUB_TERMINAL=console", then save, run "sudo update-grub", remove the CD, and reboot.

If it still doesn't work, reinstall the system from scratch and let the installer repartition the disk. When it gives you options about how you want to partition the disk, select "Use full disk" and be sure /not/ to select any option that says "LVM" on it. Once you do that, go back and do the steps in the above paragraph and it should work.